# Visualforce - image resize when render as msword

Tags: apex, visualforce, renderas, ms-word

I have a visualforce that builds word documents dynamically and I'm having troubles with the images opening in the original size. The document only resizes if the tag is set like so:

```
<img alt="" src="https://xxx--c.documentforce.com" height=175 width=350>
```

But I must to generate all images like this.

```
<img alt="" src="https://xxx--c.documentforce.com" style="height: 175px; width: 350px;">
```

Is there any treatment I can do for that?

Comment: Why "must" you use styles instead of HTML attributes? Also, why not just use both?

Comment: Because the html with the images are in a richtext field pre-populated. I'm aware that I can search the string and replace (or just add) the style for the attributes  while the document is been building but if possible I would like to have other solutions at hand.

Bear in mind the richtext field will be populated by an user with little to none html knowledge.